# Can I use Two Wifi Routers for Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

I'm in an old rented property with thick walls that are causing havoc with wifi.

Is it possible to do the following (as I already have two routers)?:
- Take two Ethernet cables out of the downstairs (Plusnet) router
- run one of them into the living room for the Xbox
- run the second one up the stairs into the study, and into the second router (Nighthawk)
- run two Ethernet cables out of the upstairs router to two PCs

Sorry if this is a really dumb question - As you can see I don't need much in the way of connectivity, but want to do it as cheaply as possible!

Alternatively, what's the easiest (and cheapest) way to achieve this simple setup?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, and actually done quite often nowadays. You will need to configure the second (upstairs) router as an access point, rather than a full-fledged router. Essentially, this means assigning it a static IP (make sure to assign one outside the DHCP range of the first router) and disabling DHCP. Some of the newer routers have a "mode" for this in their settings pages, while on others you have to change those two settings manually.

When using the second router, you may need to avoid using its WAN port. Plus the cable from the downstairs router and the 2 cables to the PCs into the LAN ports. Again, some of the newer routers, when in "Access Point mode", will repurpose that WAN port as an extra LAN port, but not all do. You'll need to check documentation for your specific model to be sure.

Comment: You may also want to put each unit on a different non-overlapping channel, and use the same SSID.